# Google Cloud SQL + Apache processes never end until server crashes - strace suggests Mysql connections hanging

Tags: mysql, apache, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, strace

Our server has a production Drupal site (runs on PHP and MySQL).
We recently migrated from a server that had MySQL installed on the server itself, to Google Cloud:

- Cloud Compute hosts the server (Centos 7).
- The Mysql database is on Cloud SQL
- PHP connects with Cloud SQL through the Google Cloud internal network (IP 10.XXX.XX.X)

Since we are on this server, the server crashes several times during the day. All memory and cpu are used. And I have to kill all processes or reboot, until it happens again.

I have scanned through all website code to search for endless loops, hanging external requests, inefficient code. Configured apache config (MaxClients etc), all to no avail.

The only possible explanation I can currently think of, is that the connection with Cloud SQL sometimes hangs forever, for no apparent reason. Similar questions on Stackoverflow suggested I take a look at the output from `strace`:

`sudo strace -tt -T -p18451 &> output` (18451 is the parent apache process)

I have never looked at strace before, and I don't know how to interpret the output. I am guessing that the "select" command is a connection to MySQL that times out. But I'm not sure at all, and also don't know where to start solving this.

Here are the outputs of the above command at a few moments:

```
16:06:02.966171 select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=215501}) = 0 (Timeout) <0.215792>
16:06:03.182158 wait4(-1, 0x7ffddf9b3adc, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED, NULL) = 0 <0.000029>
16:06:03.182260 select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=1, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout) <1.001129>
16:06:04.183521 wait4(-1, 0x7ffddf9b3adc, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED, NULL) = 0 <0.000051>
16:06:04.183655 select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=1, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout) <1.001018>
16:06:05.184774 wait4(-1, 0x7ffddf9b3adc, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED, NULL) = 0 <0.000014>
16:06:05.184849 select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=1, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout) <1.001073>
16:06:06.186021 wait4(-1, 0x7ffddf9b3adc, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED, NULL) = 0 <0.000015>
16:06:06.186135 select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=1, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout) <1.001067>
16:06:07.187298 wait4(-1, 0x7ffddf9b3adc, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED, NULL) = 0 <0.000013>
16:06:07.187370 select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=1, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout) <1.001078>
16:06:08.188559 wait4(-1, 0x7ffddf9b3adc, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED, NULL) = 0 <0.000015>
16:06:08.188649 select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=1, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout) <1.001071>
16:06:09.189901 wait4(-1, 0x7ffddf9b3adc, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED, NULL) = 0 <0.000015>
16:06:09.189975 select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=1, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout) <1.001139>
16:06:10.191208 wait4(-1, 0x7ffddf9b3adc, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED, NULL) = 0 <0.000014>
16:06:10.191280 select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=1, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout) <1.001115>
16:06:11.192587 socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC, 0) = 13 <0.000061>
16:06:11.192781 getsockopt(13, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, [212992], [4]) = 0 <0.000039>
16:06:11.192918 setsockopt(13, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUFFORCE, [8388608], 4) = 0 <0.000028>
16:06:11.193005 getuid()                = 0 <0.000027>
16:06:11.193079 geteuid()               = 0 <0.000034>
16:06:11.193165 getgid()                = 0 <0.000040>
16:06:11.193250 getegid()               = 0 <0.000026>
16:06:11.193324 sendmsg(13, {msg_name={sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/run/systemd/notify"}, msg_namelen=21, msg_iov=[{iov_base="READY=1\nSTATUS=Total requests: 8"..., iov_len=90}], msg_iovlen=1, msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, MSG_NOSIGNAL) = 90 <0.000052>
16:06:11.193474 close(13)               = 0 <0.000019>
16:06:11.193538 wait4(-1, 0x7ffddf9b3adc, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED, NULL) = 0 <0.000015>
16:06:11.193592 select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=1, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout) <1.001148>
16:06:12.194906 wait4(-1, 0x7ffddf9b3adc, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED, NULL) = 0 <0.000054>
16:06:12.195043 select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=1, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout) <1.001184>
16:06:13.196361 wait4(-1, 0x7ffddf9b3adc, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED, NULL) = 0 <0.000053>
16:06:13.196496 select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=1, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout) <1.001238>
16:06:14.197866 wait4(-1, 0x7ffddf9b3adc, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED, NULL) = 0 <0.000052>
16:06:14.198091 select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=1, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout) <1.001100>
16:06:15.199307 wait4(-1, 0x7ffddf9b3adc, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED, NULL) = 0 <0.000015>
16:06:15.199434 select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=1, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout) <1.001070>
16:06:16.200601 wait4(-1, 0x7ffddf9b3adc, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED, NULL) = 0 <0.000015>
16:06:16.200692 select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=1, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout) <1.001114>
16:06:17.201993 wait4(-1, 0x7ffddf9b3adc, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED, NULL) = 0 <0.000050>
16:06:17.202127 select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=1, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout) <1.001141>
16:06:18.203443 wait4(-1, 0x7ffddf9b3adc, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED, NULL) = 0 <0.000054>
16:06:18.203577 select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=1, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout) <1.001087>
16:06:19.204783 wait4(-1, 0x7ffddf9b3adc, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED, NULL) = 0 <0.000039>
16:06:19.204881 select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=1, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout) <1.002977>
16:06:20.207953 clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7fe2bdabab50) = 19466 <0.001983>
16:06:20.210087 wait4(-1, 0x7ffddf9b3adc, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED, NULL) = 0 <0.000015>
16:06:20.210155 select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=1, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout) <1.001105>
16:06:21.211422 socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC, 0) = 13 <0.000060>
16:06:21.211561 getsockopt(13, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, [212992], [4]) = 0 <0.000028>
16:06:21.211696 setsockopt(13, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUFFORCE, [8388608], 4) = 0 <0.000032>
16:06:21.211787 getuid()                = 0 <0.000027>
16:06:21.211861 geteuid()               = 0 <0.000027>
16:06:21.211934 getgid()                = 0 <0.000026>
16:06:21.212006 getegid()               = 0 <0.000026>


16:17:30.461828 select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=1, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout) <1.001122>
16:17:31.463080 wait4(-1, 0x7ffddf9b3adc, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED, NULL) = 0 <0.000053>
16:17:31.463227 select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=1, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout) <1.001112>
16:17:32.464486 socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC, 0) = 13 <0.000059>
16:17:32.464642 getsockopt(13, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, [212992], [4]) = 0 <0.000045>
16:17:32.464755 setsockopt(13, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUFFORCE, [8388608], 4) = 0 <0.000028>
16:17:32.464837 getuid()                = 0 <0.000026>
16:17:32.464911 geteuid()               = 0 <0.000027>
16:17:32.464984 getgid()                = 0 <0.000027>
16:17:32.465057 getegid()               = 0 <0.000033>
16:17:32.465138 sendmsg(13, {msg_name={sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/run/systemd/notify"}, msg_namelen=21, msg_iov=[{iov_base="READY=1\nSTATUS=Total requests: 1"..., iov_len=91}], msg_iovlen=1, msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, MSG_NOSIGNAL) = 91 <0.000057>
16:17:32.465255 close(13)               = 0 <0.000020>
16:17:32.465315 wait4(-1, 0x7ffddf9b3adc, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED, NULL) = 0 <0.000014>
16:17:32.465369 select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=1, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout) <1.001095>
16:17:33.466588 wait4(-1, 0x7ffddf9b3adc, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED, NULL) = 0 <0.000041>
16:17:33.466705 select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=1, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout) <1.001119>
16:17:34.467961 wait4(-1, 0x7ffddf9b3adc, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED, NULL) = 0 <0.000053>
16:17:34.468121 select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=1, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout) <1.001081>
16:17:35.469339 wait4(-1, 0x7ffddf9b3adc, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED, NULL) = 0 <0.000051>
16:17:35.469473 select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=1, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout) <1.001145>
16:17:36.470754 wait4(-1, 0x7ffddf9b3adc, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED, NULL) = 0 <0.000053>
16:17:36.470892 select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=1, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout) <1.001110>
16:17:37.472142 wait4(-1, 0x7ffddf9b3adc, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED, NULL) = 0 <0.000051>
16:17:37.472274 select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=1, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout) <1.001091>
16:17:38.473492 wait4(-1, 0x7ffddf9b3adc, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED, NULL) = 0 <0.000054>
16:17:38.473669 select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=1, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout) <1.001139>
16:17:39.474937 wait4(-1, 0x7ffddf9b3adc, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED, NULL) = 0 <0.000052>
16:17:39.475070 select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=1, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout) <1.001140>
16:17:40.476420 wait4(-1, 0x7ffddf9b3adc, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED, NULL) = 0 <0.000081>
16:17:40.476615 select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=1, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout) <1.001132>
16:17:41.477915 wait4(-1, 0x7ffddf9b3adc, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED, NULL) = 0 <0.000054>
16:17:41.478056 select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=1, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout) <1.001159>
16:17:42.479397 socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC, 0) = 13 <0.000059>
16:17:42.479538 getsockopt(13, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, [212992], [4]) = 0 <0.000029>
16:17:42.479637 setsockopt(13, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUFFORCE, [8388608], 4) = 0 <0.000029>
16:17:42.479749 getuid()                = 0 <0.000027>
16:17:42.479827 geteuid()               = 0 <0.000028>
16:17:42.479904 getgid()                = 0 <0.000026>
16:17:42.479976 getegid()               = 0 <0.000027>
16:17:42.480049 sendmsg(13, {msg_name={sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/run/systemd/notify"}, msg_namelen=21, msg_iov=[{iov_base="READY=1\nSTATUS=Total requests: 1"..., iov_len=91}], msg_iovlen=1, msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, MSG_NOSIGNAL) = 91 <0.000041>
16:17:42.480153 close(13)               = 0 <0.000021>
16:17:42.480216 wait4(-1, 0x7ffddf9b3adc, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED, NULL) = 0 <0.000016>
16:17:42.480271 select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=1, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout) <1.001094>
16:17:43.481497 wait4(-1, 0x7ffddf9b3adc, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED, NULL) = 0 <0.000052>
16:17:43.481645 select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=1, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout) <1.001140>
16:17:44.482956 wait4(-1, 0x7ffddf9b3adc, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED, NULL) = 0 <0.000052>
16:17:44.483090 select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=1, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout) <1.001128>
16:17:45.484323 wait4(-1, 0x7ffddf9b3adc, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED, NULL) = 0 <0.000015>
16:17:45.484413 select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=1, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout) <1.001156>
16:17:46.485727 wait4(-1, 0x7ffddf9b3adc, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED, NULL) = 0 <0.000052>
16:17:46.485861 select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=1, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout) <1.001126>
16:17:47.487119 wait4(-1, 0x7ffddf9b3adc, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED, NULL) = 0 <0.000062>
16:17:47.487261 select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=1, tv_usec=0}strace: Process 18451 detached



16:35:54.742455 select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=848318}) = 0 (Timeout) <0.849378>
16:35:55.592217 wait4(-1, 0x7ffddf9b3adc, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED, NULL) = 0 <0.000022>
16:35:55.592310 select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=1, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout) <1.000367>
16:35:56.592779 socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC, 0) = 13 <0.000021>
16:35:56.592867 getsockopt(13, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, [212992], [4]) = 0 <0.000011>
16:35:56.592945 setsockopt(13, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUFFORCE, [8388608], 4) = 0 <0.000012>
16:35:56.592997 getuid()                = 0 <0.000011>
16:35:56.593039 geteuid()               = 0 <0.000010>
16:35:56.593080 getgid()                = 0 <0.000010>
16:35:56.593120 getegid()               = 0 <0.000010>
16:35:56.593167 sendmsg(13, {msg_name={sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/run/systemd/notify"}, msg_namelen=21, msg_iov=[{iov_base="READY=1\nSTATUS=Total requests: 3"..., iov_len=91}], msg_iovlen=1, msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, MSG_NOSIGNAL) = 91 <0.000540>
16:35:56.593854 close(13)               = 0 <0.000017>
16:35:56.593918 wait4(-1, 0x7ffddf9b3adc, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED, NULL) = 0 <0.000021>
16:35:56.593975 select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=1, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout) <1.008668>
16:35:57.602727 wait4(-1, 0x7ffddf9b3adc, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED, NULL) = 0 <0.000023>
16:35:57.602803 select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=1, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout) <1.003837>
16:35:58.606727 wait4(-1, 0x7ffddf9b3adc, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED, NULL) = 0 <0.000022>
16:35:58.606801 select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=1, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout) <1.010840>
16:35:59.617729 wait4(-1, 0x7ffddf9b3adc, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED, NULL) = 0 <0.000021>
16:35:59.617802 select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=1, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout) <1.004837>
16:36:00.622729 wait4(-1, 0x7ffddf9b3adc, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED, NULL) = 0 <0.000022>
16:36:00.622804 select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=1, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout) <1.002846>
16:36:01.625747 wait4(-1, 0x7ffddf9b3adc, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED, NULL) = 0 <0.000024>
16:36:01.625831 select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=1, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout) <1.008807>
16:36:02.634734 wait4(-1, 0x7ffddf9b3adc, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED, NULL) = 0 <0.000022>
16:36:02.634810 select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=1, tv_usec=0}strace: Process 18451 detached
```

---

**Mysql Instance report:**

The Mysql instance is on a managed Mysql service on Google Cloud (called Cloud SQL) I cannot log on to it with SSH. Below are the instance properties in a screenshot, and queries' output as requested by Wilson Hauck

- SHOW GLOBAL STATUS: https://pastebin.com/fPDdjfME
- SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES: https://pastebin.com/PVfYt7Cc
- SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST: https://pastebin.com/NtyYDEsR
- SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST 2: https://pastebin.com/TYzGjTWB

[image]

---

And below an image of "top" on the webserver, currently during a rare moment of low CPU usage (it's midnight and the server rebooted not long ago), however it frequently sometimes jumps to 100%  CPU usage. I know that when I'll look at this tomorrow morning the process list will be full of httpd processes that never end, if I will be able to run top at all (which I usually can't by that point)

[image: TOP on webserver]

[image]

---

on webserver: ulimit -a:

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 29205
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 4096
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

on webserver: iostat -xm 5 3

```
03-05-20    _x86_64_    (2 CPU)

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
          22,07    0,00    0,80    0,07    0,00   77,07

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rMB/s    wMB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda               0,00     0,11    0,24    0,83     0,01     0,01    37,44     0,01    5,77   11,20    4,18   2,16   0,23

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
          55,73    0,00    0,91    0,00    0,00   43,36

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rMB/s    wMB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda               0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00   0,00   0,00

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0,10    0,00    0,20    0,00    0,00   99,70

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rMB/s    wMB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda               0,00     0,00    0,00    2,00     0,00     0,03    28,80     0,00    1,40    0,00    1,40   0,20   0,04
```

- apachectl -D DUMP_RUN_CFG: https://pastebin.com/Y1pXtisa
- apachectl -D DUMP_MODULES: https://pastebin.com/CKFYKtUR
- php -i: https://pastebin.com/PDzH16G4
- httpd -v:
  Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
  Server built:   Apr  2 2020 13:13:23
- httpd.conf: https://pastebin.com/ibeSqwRq
- free -m:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7317        1617        3848          49        1851        5352
Swap:          4095           7        4088
```

Comment: Additional information request. 
Google pricing model, Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
AND Optional helpful information, if available from Google Support ticket includes - 
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a   for list,
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: @WilsonHauck Thank you for looking into this. I edited the question with the queries' output, but couldn't provide all information as I can't run those other commands on the Mysql instance itself.

Comment: Thank you, analysis is in process.  If you could run the 'top' request, from some Google prompt, try to run the ulimit and iostat requests from that same prompt.  If you can not get the reports, ask your Google support team to get those reports from the appropriate server for you (where your MySQL data lives).

Comment: The MySQL doesn't run on a virtual machine and I doubt those commands can be run on wherever MySQL resides at Google since as I suppose this is a custom "serverless" setup by Google that they call Cloud SQL. Anyway I will contact them about it (don't have high hopes they will come with a useful answer tbh) I added the output from your commands run on the **webserver**, in case that would be of any use

Comment: Google may help you.  We can always hope.  Could you add to your question current A) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; and B) top report.  We need to see what has been 'added' or removed from these two reports, please.  Thanks - analysis is in process.

Comment: Thanks for the ulimit and iostat reports.  What version of APACHE are you running?  Could you post your Apache configuration, including the module directive, please.

Comment: Thanks. I added all info about my Apache/httpd on the bottom of my post. And I again ran "top" on the webserver and "show full processlist" again in MySQL, and added screenshots

Comment: When can we Skype Talk?

Comment: I have added you on Skype, you can decide what time suits you best. Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggestions to consider for your admin.even....com Google Cloud database flags

```
connect_timeout=20  # from 10 to be more tolerant for connection request
net_read_timeout=90  # from 30 to be more tolerant with read timeout
net_write_timeout=90  # from 60 to be more tolerant with write timeout
slave_net_timeout=30  # from 30 to be more tolerant with slave timeout
log_error=/mysql/logs/mysql-error.log  # from stderr (console) for documentation of err's
innodb_lru_scan_depth=100  # from 2048 to reduce 90% of CPU cycles used for function
innodb_fast_shutdown=0  # from 1 to avoid recovery on restart
max_connections=512  # from 4030 to conserve RAM footprint (if possible)
```

more tuning opportunities exist.  When I lookup Google db-n1-standard-1 the indication is 1 cpu and 3840 MB RAM, top indicates you have ~8GB RAM and iostat indicates you have 2 cpu's. Let us know of your progress in a few days, please.

Comment: Thanks Wilson for your help! I have accepted this answer as it already seems tweaking the configurations has decreased the tension on the server enough to prevent it from crashing constantly. I  still have speed issues which might get better after trying the above DB flags, I deployed that now. I will get back to let you know if that made another improvement

Comment: @Hacktisch Thank you for the feedback. We are looking forward to continuing making your path easier.

Comment: @Hacktisch Is your reliability and performance improved for the past 13 days?